# Letter replacement in string

Tags: c#

I have this simple code for letter substitution. What I would like to add is, that if i.e., I replace letter A with letter T, all T letters are automatically replaced with A as well. So if I have a word "atatatat", the following code changes the word to "tttttttt", but it should change it to "tatatata". How can I fix this?

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    String key= this.textBox1.Text;
    String letter1 = this.textBox2.Text;
    String letter2 = this.textBox3.Text;

    StringBuilder newKey = new StringBuilder();
    newKey.AppendLine(key);
    newKey.Replace(letter1, letter2);
    this.textBox4.Text = noviKljuc.ToString();
}
```

I tried with adding this line: `newKey.Replace(letter2, letter1);` But this changes word to "aaaaaaaa"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just iterate through letters and change them one by one:

```
foreach(char c in key){    
    if(c==letter1){
        newKey.Append(letter2);
    }else if(c==letter2){
        newKey.Append(letter1);
    }else{
        newKey.Append(c);
    }
}
```

Comment: Tried it, but it returns the same word as the one provided at start. No idea how tho.

Comment: Try replacing String letter1 = this.textBox2.Text; with char letter1=this.textBox2.Text[0]; . Same for letter2.

Comment: This will do a replacement of the 2nd letter even if the 1st one isn't found.

Answer (score 1):

You need to iterate over each letter, detect if you proceed with the change, and then do the second replacement only if the first one took place:

```
// Check to see if we can find the 1st char to replace in the string
bool doReplace = key.Any(c => c == originalChar);

if (doReplace)
{
    foreach (char c in key)
    {
        if (c == originalChar)
        {
            newKey.Append(alternateChar);
        }
        else if (c == alternateChar)
        {
            newKey.Append(originalChar);
        }
        else
        {
            newKey.Append(c);
        }
    }
}
else
{
    newKey = key;
}

this.textBox4.Text = newKey.ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

try this one

```
var result = String.Join("", 
   key.Select(c => c == letter2 ? letter1 : c == letter1 ? letter2 : c  ));
```